# how to pass parameter in jquery using .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day, this maybe a silly question :) how can I pass a parameter to an external javascript function using .on ?

view:

```
<script>
    var attachedPo = 0;
    $this.ready(function(){ 
    $('.chckboxPo').on('ifChecked', addPoToBill(attachedPo));
    $('.chckboxPo').on('ifUnchecked', removePoToBill(attachedPo ));
});

</script>
```

external script:

```
function addPoToBill(attachedPo){
attachedPo++;
}

function removePoToBill(attachedPo){
attachedPo--;
}
```

but Im getting an error! thanks for guiding :)

Comment: Note that only the document has a ready handler, and that passing the value of the variable as an argument doesn't update the original variable when you change the argument in the function, which means this won't work if the intention is to add and subtract from the same variable, as the arguments in each function will be local.

Comment: your absolutely right about that @adeneo ! and that what im trying to solve now :/

Comment: And here's how you'd do that -> **http://jsfiddle.net/M9wzA/**

Comment: The question becomes, do you want to update a simple counter or something else? Is this just about how to pass values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to count how many boxes are checked, via passing variable indirectly to functions try using an object instead like this:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/pBkhX/

```
var attachedPo = {
    count: 0
};
$(function () {
    $('.chckboxPo')
        .on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            addPoToBill(attachedPo);
        } else {
            removePoToBill(attachedPo);
        }
        $("#output").prepend("" + attachedPo.count + "<br/>");
    });
});

function addPoToBill(attachedPo) {
    attachedPo.count++;
}

function removePoToBill(attachedPo) {
    attachedPo.count--;
}
```

If it is not doing anything else you can simplify the whole thing to count `checked` checkboxes:

```
$(function () {
    var attachedPo = 0;
    $('.chckboxPo')
        .on('change', function () {
            attachedPo = $(".chckboxPo:checked").length;
    });
});
```

### "DOM Ready" events:

you also needed to wrap it in a ready handler like this instead of what you have now:

```
$(function(){
    ...
});
```

*Note: `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});`

You can also do the "safer version" (that ensures a locally scoped `$`) like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    ...
});
```

This works because jQuery passes a reference to itself through as the first parameter when your "on load" anonymous function is called.

There are other variations to avoid conflicts with other libraries (not very common as most modern libs know to leave `$` to jQuery nowadays). Just look up jQuery.noConflict to find out more.

Comment: @melvnberd: added some other stuff after reading the comments (and re-reading your question) :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your handlers in anonymous functions:

```
$('.chckboxPo')
    .on('ifChecked', function() {
        addPoToBill(attachedPo);
    })
    .on('ifUnchecked', function() {
        removePoToBill(attachedPo);
    });
```

You can also chain the calls to `on` as they are being attached to the same element.